# How can I assign a constant value to attributes in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

Basically what I am looking for is the Three.js equivalent to [`vertexAttrib`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/vertexAttrib). I intend to assign a constant value to my shader attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by defining `Material.defaultAttributeValues`. It's an object where the `key` is the attribute name and the `value` is the constant attribute value. For example if you want to define a constant vertex color, you can do this:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors } );
material.defaultAttributeValues = {
    color: [ 0, 0, 1 ] // blue
};
```

When doing so, it's important to avoid a buffer attribute definition with the same name. Otherwise the geometry data are used and not the values from `defaultAttributeValues`.

[Full demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g4sy6vn5/3/)

In any event, consider to use uniforms if a property is equal for all vertices. The better alternative for the above example is to define `Material.color`.

`three.js R106`